# IPv6 Problem with DNS

Tags: networking, 16.04, dns, ipv6

I have a virtual machine, accessed only through IPv6 (no IPv4 available). It is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server. I have never used an IPv6 only machine before, and therefore I must miss something trivial here.

My configuration:

1. ifconfig

> ```
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:08:d0:f9:b2  
>           inet6 addr: myIPv6Address/64 Scope:Link
>           inet6 addr: myIPv6Address/64 Scope:Global
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:27034 (27.0 KB)  TX bytes:44976 (44.9 KB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
>           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>           RX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
>           RX bytes:34008 (34.0 KB)  TX bytes:34008 (34.0 KB)
> ```

2. etc/networks

> ```
> source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
>
> iface eth0 inet6 static
>     address myIPv6Address
>     netmask 64
>     dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8844 2001:4860:4860::8888
> ```

My problem is that while I can ping google, I don't seem to have access to the rest of the internet. I cannot ping or wget from anywhere other than google (!!!)

> ```
> ping6 ipv6.google.com 
> PING ipv6.google.com(fra16s14-in-x0e.1e100.net)56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from fra16s14-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=61.2 ms 
> 64 bytes from fra16s14-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=61.3 ms 
> 64 bytes from fra16s14-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=61.3 ms
> ```

For example, while I can wget http://www.google.com I cannot get anything from github:

> ```
> wget -6 https://github.com/somefile
> --2017-01-02 13:43:54--  
> https://github.com/somefile
> Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
> wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’
> ```

What am I missing? Shouldn't be able to wget? It seems like my DNS is nopt working properly. Do I have some error on my configuration?

Comment: GitHub is not yet available on IPv6 despite years of complaints made to them which have all fallen on deaf ears. There are some IPv6 proxies to GitHub which you might be able to use to work around the problem. But we cannot recommend a specific one.

Comment: @Michael Hampton: Thank you very much for your comment. You should have add it as an answer though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is exactly as expected. Your machine only has IPv6. Google has both IPv4 and IPv6-only so you can reach them over IPv6. But GitHub only has IPv4. IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols, so they don't talk to each other.

Basically, your server and GitHub speak different languages and you're not using a translation service.

A translation protocol that lets IPv6 clients talk to IPv4 servers is called NAT64 + DNS64. Ideally the ISP where your server is hosted should provide such a service. If they don't then you can try the experimental services that a good friend of mine (Jan Žorž) hosts in his lab. You can find instructions at https://go6lab.si/current-ipv6-tests/nat64dns64-public-test/.

Please be aware that NAT64 only allows IPv6 clients to access IPv4 servers, not vice versa. So your IPv6 server will not be reachable by clients that only have IPv4. For that you would need an SIIT-DC service, but I'm not aware of anybody offering such a service.